# Calculating Stats from Dataset by Variable

Tags: sql, sas

I have a dataset in Excel that gives me test scores for each student, plus different student characteristics (race, gender, etc.). I will like to calculate the average score by these different characteristics, and then output the results to excel.

I used to have access to SAS, and was able to do this whole process using SAS and proc SQL. Given that I don't have access to SAS anymore, is there an appropriate and preferred programming language to use?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi!  This isn't really a question for StackOverflow; you're welcome to use any number of programming languages, including Excel itself, to do this.  Most users who do things like this either use Excel or Python or R, I suspect, in the "free software" space.

Comment: Excel + Pivot tables but if this is for non commercial usage, SAS Academics on Demand is free for learning or not for profit usages.

Comment: Or use the Descriptive Statistics https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/descriptive-statistics.html

Comment: Recommendations for software are out of scope for Stack Overlow.

Comment: Thanks Reeza! SAS Academics on Demand was super helpful!